# Why will my jQuery modal popup not display?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using an asp:Panel instead of a div tag (not sure that it matters) in a asp:DataGrid so that I can create modal popups linked to specific data that is being bound to the DataGrid when the page loads.

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
function ShowCommentPanel(caller) {
    $("div[id*='pnlComment'][GroupCoveragePeriodId='" + $(caller).attr("GroupCoveragePeriodId") + "']").dialog({
        width: 350,
        height: 200
    });
}
```

ASP.NET Markup:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Comment">
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="90px" CssClass="ColorBackground SubHeaderText" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="90px" CssClass="DataGridBorder Font11px" />
     <ItemTemplate>
          <div>
               <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkComment" runat="server" CssClass="IconEdit" ToolTip="Add/Edit" />
          </div>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnlComment" runat="server" title="Comment" style="display: none;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300px" Height="100px" />
          </asp:Panel>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

C# Server Code-Behind (inside the ItemDataBound handler):

```
lnkComment.Attributes.Add("GroupCoveragePeriodId", period.GroupCoveragePeriodId.ToString());
                lnkComment.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowCommentPanel(this)");
                pnlComment.Attributes.Add("SomeId", period.GroupCoveragePeriodId.ToString());
                txtComment.Attributes.Add("GroupCoveragePeriodId", period.GroupCoveragePeriodId.ToString());
                txtComment.Text = period.Comment;
```

Generated HTML Code Screenshot (from Firebug):
[image]

The application code compiles fine, the page loads fine, my JavaScript/jQuery function gets successfully called, and my jQuery selector isn't null, however it's still not showing the modal. I have no clue why none of the modals are showing, so any advice that can point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: This project I'm working on is using an outdated version of jQuery, though I doubt that's the problem. The version of jQuery it's using is v1.3.2 and the dialog functionality is courtesy of jQuery UI v1.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is looking for a `div` tag with `GroupCoveragePeriodId` (since I see no space) when this attribute is actually on the `a` tag.

Try with a space between div and [id...:

```
function ShowCommentPanel(caller) {
    $("div [id*='pnlComment'][GroupCoveragePeriodId='" + $(caller).attr("GroupCoveragePeriodId") + "']").dialog({
        width: 350,
        height: 200
    });
}
```

Note: to know if your selector got something, check if length is > 0: `alert($("div [id*='pnlComment'][GroupCoveragePeriodID='1'").length)`

Comment: Sorry that screenshot probably looked confusing because I just happened to have the top div highlighted. The Panel though is the faded-out div below the div with the a tag in it. The bottom (faded-out) div in the screenshot does have a GroupCoveragePeriodId attribute too, so I figure my selector should be finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is stupid. I don't know if I did too much Ctrl+Zing when working on debugging this issue in my ascx control, but after viewing the Firefox Console apparently I was getting an error saying that .dialog() was not a function. I swear I added the reference to the jquery-ui.js file, but I must have deleted it after too much Ctrl+Zing. Now I'm able to get the modals to pop up. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.